# Primefaces outputlabel behaves as escape = "false"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 4.0 and I am having problems with p:outputLabel.
When It is mixed with any other primefaces component it behaves like escape="false"

This field is not processed even if I specify escape="true"

Example: 
I have the following html code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="&lt;b&gt;TEXT&lt;/b&gt;" escape="true"></p:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel value="&lt;b&gt;TEXT&lt;/b&gt; " escape="true"></h:outputLabel>
</h:form>
```

And for the Output I have this

> <b>TEXT</b> <b>TEXT</b>

Which is expected behavior. (I am willing to see HTML tags as text).

But when I will add any other primefaces tag like in example:

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="&lt;b&gt;TEXT&lt;/b&gt;" escape="true"></p:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel value="&lt;b&gt;TEXT&lt;/b&gt; " escape="true"></h:outputLabel>
    <p:commandButton value="button"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Now even I have *escape="true"* I get

> **TEXT TEXT** and then the button.

Does any one have experience with this how should I fix this. 
Any suggestion.

Comment: Please note that this issue is present also on primefaces 5.0 and on primefaces 3.5.

Comment: Can't reproduce on 5.0. Are you using a custom renderer/renderkit anywhere in the webapp?

Comment: Nope I created new project just to check this and it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

I had this into my pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

I just downgraded to **2.1.11** and everything works fine.

Comment: Right, that version had indeed a bug in rendering. Why not just upgrading to current one? 2.1.29 or 2.2.8.